# Consuming BigQuery API Client through middleware and locating secrets.json files

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, next.js

I want to use a secrets folder to store my bigquery api client secrets json and use `BigQuery` [client library](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/index.html) for node to make queries to the database. But in the [documentations](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/main/samples/clientJSONCredentials.js), it shows way to load credentials from a json file and not directly.

I am using typescript to query a table and append row, In NEXT js, I am a littlebit confused about how to access the path of a secrets folder that's not going to be exposed to client side and stays in for my middleware.

Here's the function for the same:

```
import type { NextApiHandler } from 'next';
import axios from 'axios';
import { BigQuery } from '@google-cloud/bigquery';
import bqSecrets from '../../../bigquery/keys.json';
const options = {
  keyFilename: '../../../secrets/keys.json',
  projectId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
};

const bigquery = new BigQuery(options);

const submitUserData: NextApiHandler = async (request, response) => {
  const { geoData, googleData, post, userRole } = request.body;
  if (!post) response.json({ error: false, msg: 'Not Required' });
  else {
    delete googleData.isAuthenticated;

    

    try {
      const rep = await bigquery
        .dataset('stackconnect')
        .table('googleoAuth')
        .insert([requestPayload]);
      console.log(await rep);
      response.json({ error: false, msg: 'Success' });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error = ', e);
      response.json({ error: true, msg: 'Error' });
    }
  }
};
```

But this throws an error saying: `File not Found`. Can someone help me identify about how to either locate the file in NEXT or how can I directly pass the JSON data using BQ Node Client?

Additionally, I want to know in NEXT, which is the ideal place to store secrets that are not exposed to client side?

Answer (score 1):

After digging into the source code, I realized that there's an attribute called credentials, and so I was able to make it work by doing the following modification:

```
import bqSecrets from '../../../bigquery/keys.json';
const options = {
  credentials: bqSecrets,
  projectId: 'project_id',
};

const bigquery = new BigQuery(options);
```

I hope this helps anyone who's looking to directly inject the json credentials to the BigQuery Node Client.

Additionally, I am still not very sure about the file structure of NEXT as I still don't know if any other assets than those placed under public folder are exposed to client side or not.